# Capybara + Selenium does not open browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

I have added the following configuration in my rails_helper file:

```
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new( app, :profile => profile)
  end
  Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium

  Capybara.app_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

and I have installed the Selenium IDE in my chrome explorer, and I have added the following test to try it out:

```
RSpec.describe 'User creation', feature: true do
  scenario 'done from the registration form' do
    visit root_path
    expect(page).to have_content('cookies')
  end
```

I also tried with `js: true`, and I was expecting the chrome explorer to open and see capybara performing the tasks I would be adding. The test does run:

```
Finished in 0.78308 seconds (files took 5.4 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

I also tried adding:

```
RSpec.describe 'User creation', js: true, driver: :selenium_chrome do
```

Comment: Could the driver be configured in headless mode? Then you won't see a window pop up. Either way, one thing you can try is to explicitly set the driver for the example, i.e. `RSpec.describe 'User creation', driver: :selenium do ...` (or `RSpec.describe 'User creation', driver: :selenium_chrome do ...`)

Comment: I tried with those, but none of them worked.

Comment: What tutorial are you following? It really seems like you've missed some of the steps and you should never be setting `app_host` to port 3000